# Cannot get mouse position in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

**Paint class:**

```
public class Paint extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Image swimmingpool;
    Mouse swim = new Mouse();
    Timer tm = new Timer(7, this);
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println(swim.getdistance()); //prints out 0 ?!?


ImageIcon swimminghold = new ImageIcon(render.class.getResource("resources/Swimmingpoolns.png")); 
    swimmingpool = swimminghold.getImage();
    g.drawImage(swimmingpool, 0,-40,null); 
        if (swim.getdistance() >= 3) {
            System.out.println("test works");
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

}
```

**Mouse class**

```
public class Mouse implements MouseMotionListener {
    private int x1 = 200;
    private int y1 = 165;
    double distance;
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {


double distance1 = Math.pow((e.getX() - x1), 2);
        double distance2 = Math.pow((e.getY() - y1), 2);

        setdistance(Math.sqrt(distance1 + distance2));
        // The below prints, and has been
        // tested to print the correct distance
        System.out.println(getdistance());
    }
    public void setdistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
    public double getdistance() {
        return distance;
    }
}
```

When I execute  `System.out.println(getdistance())` in the Mouse class it prints the correct distance whereas if I execute `System.out.println(swim.getdistance());` in the paint class prints `0`.

Everything I've tried to do still results in `distance = 0`, in the class `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Incidentally, you have different parentheses for calculating `distance1` and `distance2`

Comment: `^` isn't an exponentiation operator in Java, it represents a BITWISE XOR operation. Use [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-)

Comment: You should add the Listener as Listener. You only create this object "mouse" and nothing more. The mouseMove- method never calls. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

Comment: Thankyou everyone for your quick replies , I do apologize in advance for my code as I'm still new to this. @Hunter McMillen  I've updated the code.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 Its added in another class that i haven't added. I add it to the JFrame I created called frame. Mouse swim = new Mouse();      frame.addMouseMotionListener(swim);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Hunter-mcmillen: you are confused about java operators.

```
public  void  mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) { 

        double distance1 = Math.pow((e.getX() - x1),2);
        double distance2 = Math.pow((e.getY() - y1),2); // Math.pow(a,b) == a^b (in a calculator)

        setdistance(Math.sqrt(distance1 + distance2));
        System.out.println(getdistance()); 
}
```

I really recommend that you read more carefully the [Java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) before assuming how they work on the language.

**EDIT 2:**

I recommend also that you create a JPanel or JLabel for this picture, and then load such picture inside this new Jpanel or Label or other component.

```
public class Paint extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Mouse swim = new Mouse();
    Timer tm = new Timer(7, this);
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Try this:
    ImageIcon swimminghold = new ImageIcon(render.class.getResource("resources/Swimmingpoolns.png")); 
    swimmingpool = swimminghold.getImage();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(swimminghold);
    label.addMouseMotionListener(swim);
    addMouseMotionListener(swim);
    label.addMouseMotionListener(swim);
    addMouseMotionListener(swim);

        //Do something

        /* ...*/
}
```

Comment: Ive updated the code however in "public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {" swim.getdistance() is still printing 0

Comment: the problem is that  getdistance() is always returning 0 in "public void paintComponent(Graphics g).

Comment: @arunptl100, I didn't understand this last comment.

Comment: Ive updated the code to show the loading of images , however moving away from that , any variables that are changed outside of public void paintComponent(Graphics g) will not update in public void paintComponent(Graphics g) no matter what i try;

Comment: in my case , in the Mouse class , i store a variable called distance I created a getter for this variable. Whenever I call this getter in public void paintComponent(Graphics g) it will always show 0 , not updating. This getter works anywhere else apart from public void paintComponent(Graphics g).

Comment: In the code i do swim.getdistance() >= 3) in paintComponent. Ive also tried to print swim.getdistance() but it prints 0